# Update tuple in list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Ok, so I want to do something like:

```
if title and articleNumber in listOfData:
    listOfData[articleNumber].update(title, articleNumber, None, oldvariants + variants)
else:
    listOfData.append((title, articleNumber, None, variants))
```

I realize that the syntax is not correct, but since I don't know what I want to do, I described it as the syntax I would want to use :) The article number is a large integer (i don't know if it can start with 0)

Note that I don't want to use a dictionary, since listOfData should be the same format as other parts of the code. (This is unfortunate, because the articles i'm parsing is divided on several rows in some cases which makes me need this check if it is in the list already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update a tuple in place, by its definition.  Its immutable.  You can however replace it completely.

```
if title and articleNumber in listOfData:
    listOfData[articleNumber] = (title, articleNumber, None, oldvariants + variants)
else:
    listOfData.append((title, articleNumber, None, variants))
```

`update` is a dictionary method to add an entry which makes me think that you might be trying to have one entry in list of data consist of more than one tuple.  If this is the case you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Articlenumber is out of range and I don't think that ``if title and articleNumber in listOfData:`` is working, since it looks for the single value title and article number, not the tuple containing those

Comment: do you mean to do `if (title, articleNumber) in listOfData` ?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
listOfData[articleNumber] = (title, articleNumber, None, oldvariants + variants)
```

Comment: Article number is out of range

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
if title == listOfData[articleNumber][0]:
    oldvariants=lisOfData[articleNumber][3]
    listOfData[articleNumber]=(title, articleNumber, None, oldvariants + variants)
else:
    listOfData.append((title, articleNumber, None, variants))
```

**EDIT**

correcting mistake in the if

Comment: Out of range as I commented on other answers as well

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like an dictionary with the key as a tuple (articleNumber,title)

```
if (articleNumber,title) in dictionaryContent:
     dictionaryContent[(articleNumber,title)] += variants
else:
     dictionaryContent[(articleNumber,title)] = variants
```

and then convert it to a list:

```
for (articleNumber, title) in dictionaryContent.keys():
    listOfData.append((title, articleNumber, None, dictionaryContent[item]))
```